# no me guarda registros en base de datos mysql

Tags: php, mysql

pongo mi código para registrar pero al momento de guardar, no me guarda nada en la base de datos esta tabla la tome de internet y funciona bien, pero le agregue dos campos mas, direccion y email, pero al momento de guardar los datos, no guarda nada en mi tabla, se que tengo que cambiar mysql por mysqli o PDO, pero no creo que la falla este ahi
muchas gracias

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
//print_r($_POST);
include "conexion.php";
if(isset($_POST))
{
$insert="INSERT INTO contacto 
(nombre,apellido_paterno,apellido_materno,telefono,direccion,email)
VALUES(
'".$_POST['nombre']."',
'".$_POST['apellido_paterno']."',
'".$_POST['apellido_materno']."',
'".$_POST['telefono']."',
'".$_POST['direccion']."',
'".$_POST['email']."'
 )";
//print_r($insert);
mysql_query($insert, $link);
}
?>
 <html>
     <head>
        <title>Mi Agenda</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css" type="text/css" media=screen>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

    <div id="header"><b>Mi Agenda</b></div>
    <div id="menu">

    <div class="seccion"><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></div>
    <div class="seccion"><a href="registrar.php">Registrar contacto</a>
    </div>
    <div class="seccion"><a href="listar.php">Listar contacto</a></div>



    </div>
    <div id="content">
    <h2>Registrar contacto</h2>
            <form method="POST">
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Nombre:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="nombre"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Apellido Paterno:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="apellido_paterno"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Apellido Materno:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="apellido_materno"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Telefono:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="telefono"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>direccion:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="direccion"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Email:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email"/></td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Aceptar"/>
                <input type="reset" value="Cancelar"/></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Desarrollado por Diego - Copyright Todos los Derechos 
    Reservados</div>

   </div>

   </body>
   </html>

   <?php
   mysql_close($link);
    ?>
```

mi codigo para listar

```
 <?php
 include "conexion.php";
 $query="SELECT * FROM contacto";
 $resultado = mysql_query($query);
 //print_r($resultado);
 while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
 {
 //print_r($fila);
 $contactos[]=$fila;

 }

  //print_r($contactos);
  ?>
     <html>
      <head>
       <title>Mi agenda</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css" type="text/css" media=screen>

    </style>
   </head>
     <body>

  <div id="container">

    <div id="header"><b>Mi Agenda</b></div>
    <div id="menu">

    <div class="seccion"><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></div>
    <div class="seccion"><a href="registrar.php">Registrar contacto</a>
    </div>
    <div class="seccion"><a href="listar.php">Listar contacto</a></div>


    </div>
    <div id="content">
    <h2>Lista de contactos</h2>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
                <th>Apellido Materno</th>
                <th>Teléfono</th>
                                    <th>direccion</th>
                                    <th>email</th>
            </tr>

            <?php
                foreach($contactos as $c)
                                    {
                    echo"
                    <tr>
                        <td>".$c['id']."</td>
                        <td>".$c['nombre']."</td>
                        <td>".$c['apellido_paterno']."</td>
                        <td>".$c['apellido_materno']."</td>
                        <td>".$c['telefono']."</td>
                        <td>".$c['direcion']."</td>
                        <td>".$c['email']."</td>

                    </tr>


                    ";



                }

            ?>

            </table>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Desarrollado por Diego - Copyright Todos los Derechos 
    Reservados</div>

  </div>

  </body>
   </html>
    <?php
    mysql_close($link);
    ?>
```

mi tabla ensql

```
 -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
 -- version 4.6.4
 -- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
 --
 -- Servidor: X.X.X.99
  -- Tiempo de generaciÃ³n: 06-04-2017 a las 18:55:14
  -- VersiÃ³n del servidor: 5.7.14
    -- VersiÃ³n de PHP: 5.6.25

    SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
  SET time_zone = "+00:00";


     /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
     /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
     /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
     /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

     --
     -- Base de datos: `***********`
     --
```

---

```
      --
      -- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `contacto`
        --

 CREATE TABLE `contacto` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `apellido_paterno` text NOT NULL,
 `apellido_materno` text NOT NULL,
 `nombre` text NOT NULL,
 `foto` text NOT NULL,
 `telefono` text NOT NULL,
 `direccion` text NOT NULL,
 `email` text NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Ãndices para tablas volcadas
 --

  --
  -- Indices de la tabla `contacto`
  --
   ALTER TABLE `contacto`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

 --
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `contacto`
 --
  ALTER TABLE `contacto`
   MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: ya le agregue esa corercion, pero nada :(

Comment: Modifica tu linea del mysql_query, por esta que te coloco aquí, para que puedas ver si te esta dando algún error :**$result=mysql_query($insert,$link)or die (mysql_error());**. Ahora si gustas te puedo, hacer una función que te haga todo el proceso de **insert** a partir de una array o un string como prefieras. Eso se hace con el fin de adelantar trabajo y disminuir errores.

Comment: _se que tengo que cambiar mysql por mysqli o PDO, pero no creo que la falla este ahi muchas gracias_ Cambia cuanto antes, te aseguro que te ahorrarás mucho tiempo. En lugar de perder tiempo queriendo hacer que un código **obsoleto e inseguro funcione**, pásate a PDO o MySQLi. Además, existen clases ya preparadas que te ahorrarán la mayor parte del trabajo. Mira por ejemplo aquí: https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO Es una clase que estoy creando, modestia aparte. Me funciona bien y para usarla es muy fácil, como se explica en la parte de abajo del enlace. Saludos.

Comment: @novato qué error te da? La pregunta no puede ser respondida correctamente sin saber cuál es el error

Answer (score 1):

Proba cambiarle el id de tu tabla. Usa integer con autoincremental.

```
ALTER TABLE `contacto` CHANGE `id` `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Esta es la condición que use antes de hacer el insert.

```
if( !isset($_POST['']) and !empty($_POST['nombre']) ){ .. }
```

Luego de este cambió a mi me funciono tu código de registrar.php

Comment: Parece un buen punto, pero ya está como autoincremental en el código de la pregunta

Answer (score -1):

En primer lugar estas usando unas funciones de mysql que están desde la version de php 5.5.0 en desuso, y posteriormente eliminadas en la version 7.0.0  ("http://php.net/manual/es/intro.mysql.php"), para una mejor funcionalidad te recomiendo usar la extension mysqli ("http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php").

Tendrías que seguir los mismos procedimientos.

```
<?php
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("ejemplo.com", "usuario", "contraseña", "basedatos");

    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $apellido_paterno = $_POST["apellido_paterno"];
    $apellido_materno = $_POST["telefono"];
    $direccion = $_POST["direccion"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];

    $insert = "INSERT INTO contacto (nombre,apellido_paterno,apellido_materno,telefono,direccion,email) VALUES('$nombre','$apellido_paterno','$apellido_materno','$direccion','$email')";
    mysqli_query($mysqli,$insert);
?>
```

Comment: Te nombro una función que se utiliza para evitar SQL-INJECTION("para que no te toquen las narices los hackers") -> http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: @CristíanMartínezMontes no, me tira error brogracias

Answer (score -1):

Hola te dejo aquí una función con mysql para ver si te sirve:

```
       function insert_db($tbname, $cvalue, $dvalue){

       if($cvalue == "" OR $cvalue == null){
           echo "Verifique el datos de los campos"; 
           return false;
       }

       if($dvalue == "" OR $dvalue == null){
           echo "Verifique el los datos de los valores"; 
           return false;
       }

       $sql= "INSERT INTO ".$tbname." ('".$cvalue."')";
       $sql .= " values (".$dvalue.")";
       $insertResult = mysql_query($sql,$link) or die (mysql_error());
       return $insertResult;

   }
```

Para usarla te dejo el ejemplo:

```
    $tbname = 'contacto ';
    $cvalue = 'nombre,apellido_paterno,apellido_materno,telefono,direccion,email';
    $dvalue = "$_POST['nombre'],$_POST['apellido_paterno'],$_POST['apellido_materno'],$_POST['telefono'],$_POST['direccion'],$_POST['email']";
    insert_db($tbname,$cvalue,$dvalue);
```